# How to filter ngrx store items in angular?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Hi I am learning to use ngrx.

I am using effects to fetch  data.

```
loadItems$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ItemActions.loadItems),
  mergeMap(action =>
    this.defaultService.getItems().pipe(
      map(Items => ItemActions.loadItemsSuccess({ Items })),
      catchError(error =>
        of(ItemActions.loadItemsFailure({ error }))
      )
    )
  )
)
)
```

Can someone suggest me how to apply a list of filters on the items received by the store?

Comment: Not clear what you need exactly. You can use operators, either on your service or in your effect to transform your data any way you want..

Comment: Thankyou for replying. I have a bunch of items in my store (retrieved via effects). How can if filter these items based on the item properties such as item name, timestamp, item price etc...?

Comment: I could have used services for filtering. But I need to leverage full potential of ngrx.

Comment: So if all data is in your store, you could use selectors for different filter actions maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter data in an effect or in a selector you should use normal javascript tools like `Array.filter`, `Array.reduce` etc.

for example if you want to filter them in an effect.

```js
loadItems$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ItemActions.loadItems),
        mergeMap(action =>
            this.defaultService.getItems().pipe(
                map(Items => ItemActions.loadItemsSuccess({
                  Items: Items.filter(item => item.active) })), // Array.filter
                catchError(error =>
                    of(ItemActions.loadItemsFailure({ error }))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

or in selector you can use `map` operator.

```js
this.store.select(selectItems).pipe(
  map(items => items.filter(item => item.active)), // Array.filter
);
```